# list each specific element with parent name

Tags: jq

I have json with random elements on array:

```
[
  {
    "system": {
      "name": "sys1",
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "ip": "1.1.1.1",
          "ent": "ent1"
        },
        {
          "ip": "2.2.2.2",
          "ent": "ent0"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "system": {
      "name": "sys2",
      "interfaces": [
        {
          "ip": "3.3.3.3",
          "ent": "ent0"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "system": {
      "name": "sys3",
      "interfaces": null
    }
  },
  {
    "system": {
      "name": "sys4"
    }
  }
]
```

I need get following output with `jq`:

```
sys1    1.1.1.1 ent1
sys1    2.2.2.2 ent0
sys2    3.3.3.3 ent0
```

I tried following filter:

```
$ jq -r '.[]|[.system.name, .system.interfaces[].ip, .system.interfaces[].ent]|@tsv' test_json2
sys1    1.1.1.1 2.2.2.2 ent1    ent0
sys2    3.3.3.3 ent0
```

How to split line 1 to achieve expected result?

Update: I met new case when array is null and I get now following error using filrer from pmf's answer:

```
jq: error (at test_json2:34): Cannot iterate over null (null)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterate outside the array which contains the `.name`. That way, another array is generated for each iteration step.

```sh
jq -r '.[].system | [.name] + (.interfaces[]? | [.[]]) | @tsv' test_json2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1obJ7HB6EX)

If the objects in the `.interfaces` array can have more than just those two field, but you only want to output said two fields, name them explicitly.

```sh
jq -r '.[].system | [.name] + (.interfaces[]? | [.ip, .ent]) | @tsv' test_json2
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/qyF8FMz6KJ)

Output is:

```
sys1    1.1.1.1 ent1
sys1    2.2.2.2 ent0
sys2    3.3.3.3 ent0
```

Comment: Thank you it works great but fails when in json there is "null" array or does not exist. I have updated json example in my question. How to skip this error?

Comment: @DonJ Simply change `.interfaces[]` to `.interfaces[]?` (add a question mark)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array` to group each interface.

```
.[] | .system | select(.name=="sys1" or .name=="sys2") | [.name] + (.interfaces[] | [.[]]) | @tsv
```

Demo

https://jqplay.org/s/iucSZqkB1r

Note that `.[]` on an object returns its `values`.